# Handling Array values - unset or array_pop

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, array-population

I have a post value like this.
It is stored in `$_POST`.
Now, I need to remove or unset the last array value i.e `[submit] => Add`.
When I checked in SOF, they asked me to use `array_pop`.
But that didn't work. Any help.

**My output:**

```
    [56-1] => 0
    [56-2] => 0
    [56-3] => 0
    [submit] => Add
```

**Expected output:**

```
        [56-1] => 0
        [56-2] => 0
        [56-3] => 0
```

EDITED:

Here is my code

```
    <?php 
    $my_array = $_POST;
    foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){
    array_pop($my_array);
    unset($key['submit']);
    }
    print_r($my_array);
    ?>
```

Thanks,

Kimz

Comment: your question's unclear..can you explain it further or some code will help.

Comment: check my question again. i have pasted my code

Comment: can you also put the unexpected output in your OP ?

Comment: You do not need a `foreach` loop. The array_pop should happen only once and thus out of the loop. More [here](http://php.net/array_pop)

Comment: what is `unset($key['submit']);` meant to do? I would guess this would give you a warning. $key is a string, and `$key['submit']` doesn't exist...

Comment: array_pop should work.. please did make those values into array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

unset($_POST['submit']);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_array = $_POST;
```

Don't need to use loop.
You should do:

`unset($my_array['submit'])`;

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<?php 
    $my_array = $_POST;
    foreach($my_array as $key=>$value){ // this foreach will eventually pop ALL your items
        echo "foreach is now at value: $value<br/>"; // remove this line if you remove the foreach
        echo "but now removing the last value of array (pop), which is value: "
        echo array_pop($my_array) . "<br/>";
        echo "done<br/>";
        // unset($key['submit']); // remove this line. this is foobar. $key['submit'] will never exist.
    }
    print_r($my_array); // with the foreach, this will print nothing (empty). without the foreach, only the last line would print...
?>
```